# Pause and Resumeable timer?

Tags: android, timer, handler, timertask

In a game I am developing I want to create a delay. The delay am I makeing is using a handler with this code:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               animationDrawable.start();

                }
        },theDelay);
```

The problem is that I got a pause button that is going to make everything stop, and not do anything until you resume again. For now it is running even though the gameplay is paused. I got a boolean that is changed when I want to pause the activity.

I have searched for solutions using a Thread, TimerTask and Handler, but for everyone of these I have seen warning about that non of these is safe to use.

How can I pause and resume this "countdown" in a secure way, and without haveing to start it all over again when resuming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I pause and resume this "countdown" in a secure way, and without having to start it all over again when resuming?

1. save the start time  when you start the handler  like this -  `startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`
2. inside the `onPause` save that time `pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` and cancel the hendler
3. inside `onResume` recreate the event with the `pauseTime - startTime`

Comment: How can I get the time left, and is it not possible to do this with a handler using removeCallBacks?

Comment: create two int,  startTime when you start the event and the second when you pause the event, if we do the math second - startTime = the time left